# How can I get the keyboard shortcut for a given emacs command?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

Is there any function to do this? something like the inverse of "describe-key"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the command `where-is`, for example:

```
M-x where-is find-file
```

Comment: Obviously, you should start with `M-x where-is RET where-is RET`.

Answer (score 16):

You can try **C-h w** (it's bound to the **where-is** command).

Answer (score 8):

Type `M-x describe-function` or `C-h f` then type in the function name you want to know about. It will display the key bindings associated to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Lugaru's Epsilon Emacs, it is "[describe-command](http://www.lugaru.com/man/describe-command.html)".